# get the last 10 number of NSData

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdata

I need to get the last 2 number of NSData, does anyone know how to solve this issue? 
Here is the NSdata:

```
<616263>
```

and I need the last 2, (63). I used the `subdataWithRange` but it doesn't work.

Any help appreciate.

Comment: What kind of data is it? I mean NSString, NSNumber or something else, is there specific use you want to subdata the NSData?

Comment: It is NSData...

Comment: *The last 2 number* is actually the last byte, you can get it with range `NSMakeRange(data.length - 1, 1)`. @Balanced The question is not about Swift.

Comment: "I used the subdataWithRange but it doesn't work.": What have you tried? Because you should be able to get it. What range did you used? Potentially the issue is there. But it's better if you show what you've tried, and help you understand what you misunderstood rather than give you a direct answer. Also you want "63" as a NSData, not 63 int value, right?

Comment: Thanks it works @vadian

Comment: @Steven Glad it worked for your, still I want to know the use of it, why would I subData the NSData, can you share please? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSString *string = @"abc";
NSData *data = [string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@",data);      //Print :- <616263>
NSLog(@"%@",[data subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(2, 1)]); //Print :- <63>
```